# How to check if Hudson is executing any build for more than x minutes?

Tags: hudson

1. How can I check if a build is running for more than X minutes? Does [Hudson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%28software%29) have some XML API for it? I want the API to be independent of the job, so I can call a URL from my remote machine to check if Hudson is executing any build or any job for more than x minutes.
2. It may be the case that the job that Hudson is executing is stuck or hanged. How can I identify that?
3. My idea is if a build is taking too long I will just restart the system or kill all its processes

I will call a URL, say `http://myhudsonserver/something`, and I should get some XML by which I can make out.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [build timeout plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

You may find the Hudson [Remote Access API](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Remote+access+API) of use.